# How big is Warehouse 13?

Tags: sy-fy, warehouse-13

How big is Warehouse 13 (i.e. in square feet), and is it practical to build a warehouse of its size?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I just read [an interview](http://io9.com/5595628/eureka-and-warehouse-13-talk-felicia-day-a-mysterious-new-regent-a-major-character-return-and-the-big-crossover) which has the following quote:

> When the panel was asked how big the Warehouse actually is, the answers ran the gamut from extremely large to impossibly huge. Joanne Kelly said it was infinite, while Allison Scagliotti suggested it was constantly expanding, much like the universe itself. Saul Rubinek tried for a more prosaic answer, guessing that, since the Warehouse is the sum of all twelve that came before it, it must extend about three miles into the mountain. Jack Kenny suggested the precise dimensions didn't matter - what was really important is that we never see the back of the warehouse, that it continue to go on forever.

So, I guess it is quite large, and that it doesn't seem to have a back to it.

Answer (score 9):

No official info to the best of my knowledge, but several places on the net mention that the zip line is ~2 miles long (~10k ft).

I don't recall having perpendicular zip lines, so the width of the warehouse is questionable - let's assume 200-500 feet wide so you can travel quickly to/from zip line.

That would net you 2 – 5 million square feet.

Is it practical? Sure. Boeing plant is 398,000 m² - 4.3 million sq ft (from http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_buildings_in_the_world ).

Comment: I can't parse "2mm-5mm square feet". You clearly don't mean millimeters (the standard meaning of "mm"), but what *do* you mean?

Comment: mm is 1,000,000 (derived from a thousand thousand, where m is roman for a thousand). I think it's used to disambiguate, since in some countries a "million" is 1,000 and in some it's 1,000,000.

Comment: @ASmor Isn't that really a billion?  I.e.  A billion in england is a million millions.  Whereas in the US a billion is 1000 millions.

Comment: What Asmor said.

Comment: @Asmor: The Roman numeral for 1000 is *M*, not *m*.

Comment: @Martha - both mm and MM denote Million (see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MM). Thanks for disambiguating edit though :)

Comment: @DVK: Take another look at your wikipedia link:  "mm" is for millimeter and "MM" the Roman numeral for 2000.  You seem to be thinkig of "Mm".

Comment: Izk - quoting Wiki: `MM or mm, million`

Comment: I have never seen mm mean million in any context. I don't know which locales it exists in, but I've never seen it used in the UK. M means million, k means thousand, etc.

Answer (score 4):

I do not know the current size, but it's size is infinite due to the expansion joints, which use E=mc2 to covert into energy, which allows the warehouse to expand, and the warehouse is not just a building, it is a living thing, it's consciousness is connected with that of ms. frederics.

Comment: Is there canon support for this?

Comment: There is canon to support this.  It was one of the plot points for an episode in season 5.

Comment: yes, in "all the time in the world" they mention the Eldunari, which the care takers mind is a reflection of, and in "instinct" the gold spike from the trans-continental railroad get caught in an expansions joint, causing the ware house to expand unevenly